# Error when selecting rows in pandas dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like this:

```
col1  col2 col3
 A     45    4
 A     3     5
 B     2     5
```

I want to make a separate dataframe, `df2`, which only has the rows where `col` in `df` equals `A`. Hence it should look like:

```
col1  col2 col3
 A     45    4
 A     3     5
```

I just use `df2=df1.loc[df1['col1']=='A']`. However this returns the error: `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

What you tried works for me, you can try this:

```
df2 = df[df.col1 == 'A']
```

**Output**

```
  col1  col2    col3
0   A   45      4
1   A   3       5
```

**Edit**
Tested on pandas version

```
pd.__version__
'1.2.4'
```

Comment: This gives me NA values on the columns except from `col1` and also returns all the rows of the df

Comment: which pandas version are you using?

Comment: I am using pandas version 1.2.0. But the command you suggested does work in other df's I use

Comment: Can you run df.info() and share the output

Answer (score -1):

Just try:

```
df.query("col1=='A'")
```

Comment: this gives the error `col1 is not defined`

Comment: Can you share the output of `df.columns`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29157920)

Comment: @HarshadPansuriya Seems like an answer to me... If you think it's wrong - downvote, don't vote to delete...

Comment: Well it might happen that there is a space in the column name.  That's why I asked. I don't know what wrong in that....